# Access a field from another table using the object relation

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am new to *SalesForce* and *SOQL* so sorry in advance if the question has already been answered, if yes link it to me.

The aim of my *SOQL* query is to get all the contract information to generate PDF.

**There are tables:** *Contract*, *Contact* and *Account*

**In the Contract table there are fields:** *Maitre_d_apprentissage__c*, *MaitreApprentissageNom1__c*, *MaitreApprentissagePrenom1__c*, *Apprenti__c*, *ApprentiNom__c*, *ApprentiPrenom__c*

**There are relationships:**

- *Apprenti__r* which link *Apprenti__c* to *Contact* table
- *Maitre_d_apprentissage__r* which link *Maitre_d_apprentissage__c* to *Contact* table

When I looked at table, I saw that *MaitreApprentissageNom1__c* was equal to *Maitre_d_apprentissage__r.LastName* and *ApprentiNom__c* was equal to *Apprenti__r.LastName*. So I conclude I could get other information of *Apprenti__c* and *Maitre_d_apprentissage__c* from the *Contact* Table following the same principle. So I added to my query *Apprenti__r.Date_de_naissance__c* and *Maitre_d_apprentissage__r.Date_de_naissance__c* to get the Date_de_naissance__c field which is in my Contact table.

I see in the results that the query succeeds in getting the information but some values have changed column (lines 6 and 7), you can see the difference between query 1 and query 2. In the first query I only return the *Apprenti__r.Date_de_naissance__c* and in the second query I return *Apprenti__r.Date_de_naissance__c* and *Maitre_d_apprentissage__r.Date_de_naissance__c*

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT ApprentiNom__c, ApprentiPrenom__c, Apprenti__r.Date_de_naissance__c, MaitreApprentissageNom1__c, MaitreApprentissagePrenom1__c
FROM Contract
```

**Result 1:**

[image: Result of query 1]

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT ApprentiNom__c, ApprentiPrenom__c, Apprenti__r.Date_de_naissance__c, MaitreApprentissageNom1__c, MaitreApprentissagePrenom1__c, Maitre_d_apprentissage__r.Date_de_naissance__c
FROM Contract
```

**Result 2:**

[image: Result of query 2]

I would like to understand from where is coming the problem and how to correct it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that it's just your query editor displaying stuff incorrectly. You can see it got confused with 2 lookups to Contact table, why there's even a column header "Contact.Date_de_naissance__c" (and why it's there twice). And they aren't shown in the order you requested...

What editor you're using? You could try built-in "Developer Console" or http://workbench.developerforce.com/

What do you need it for? In Apex order of fields won't matter, in REST API query the values fetched via lookup will come as JSON sub-objects so there will always be a way to figure out exactly which value is coming from which relation.

In Dev Console try to run this and check if it solves your fears:

```
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty([SELECT 
    ApprentiNom__c, ApprentiPrenom__c, 
    Apprenti__r.Date_de_naissance__c, 
    
    MaitreApprentissageNom1__c, MaitreApprentissagePrenom1__c, 
    Maitre_d_apprentissage__r.Date_de_naissance__c
FROM Contract]));
```

Then add `Maitre_d_apprentissage__r.LastName` to query and see what changed, what stayed as is.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm using http://workbench.developerforce.com/ to develop my query. We don't know yet if we will be using APEX or REST API. We use Node.js to query SalesForce. Anyway as you said we will have a way to get what we want. I will try your solution on Monday (I can't try before) and come back to you after :)

Comment: Yes, Workbench behaves bit funny with displaying "parent" relationship queries (the ones where you use dot to go "up"). Don't worry, you will probably be all right, try my version or in workbench use "View as: Bulk CSV" for example and view it in Excel.

Comment: It seems that the "Developer Console" is giving me the right result. Thank you :)